# rails asset pipeline broken in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

i have searched and search but cannot find an answer to my problem.  it looks to me like the asset pipeline in my development environment is broken.  i have a generic application.css file that contains:

```
*= require start
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

in the app/assets/stylesheets directory, i have a style.css file.  it is my understanding that this file should be included in the html as a separate link in development but all i get in my html is:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the end result of the issue is that the formatting in style.css is not appearing in development.  i should note that everything works fine in production (heroku.)

i'm new to the asset pipeline so i'm unsure what other information would be helpful but i'm happy to provide additional information.

EDIT:

i've worked around the issue by adding:

```
*= require style
```

to application.css and then adding:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "style", :media => "all" %>
```

to my application layout.  this fixes the problem.  now my question is, why is "require_tree ." not picking up style.css in development but does pick it up in production?

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline is only used in production.
In development, assets are served directly from /public, so the inclusion of the pipeline doesn't apply.  You won't see the reference in application.css because they are served direectly from app/assets

As fopr them not appearing in development itself, I'm not sure why that is.
Please verify that assets/stylesheets/style.css exists in the local environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it was my understanding that in development, the asset pipeline _is_ used but via the sprockets engine.  it is suggested that assets be precompiled in production to avoid the sprockets engine overhead and in that case are served from /public or whatever cache is configured.